# Trying to remote desktop into an Apple

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, apple

I'm trying to remote into a Mac (OSX 10.11.5) from Ubuntu 16.04. I tried with [Remmina](http://www.remmina.org/wp/) via VNC. However, it appears to connect at first. But almost immediately after it appears the Remmina window crashes.

Can I remote into a Mac OSX box from an Ubuntu instance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can do it from an Ubuntu session using Remmina.  I have set one up and it is working fine.  I do have mine hardwired to my network, and my connection opens at the *Poor (fastest)* quality connection.

In the screenshot below, you can see how I have my MacBook setup for Screen Sharing.

[image]

Then in Remmina, I set it to VNC, put in the IP address of my MacBook Pro and clicked Quick Connect.

[image]

Then typed in my short username from the Mac and my password, and it is stable and working fine.  *The top screenshot is actually from my Remmina session connected to my Mac.*

[image]

Also make sure to set the color depth to greater than 8bpp in the profile if you create one:

[image]

If yours is set this way, and still having problems, you might want to try removing and reinstalling Remmina.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked. I had to set color depth to 15 bit. It wasn't happy otherwise. Also managed to get SSH tunnel as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Rick 
Thx!) Color depth more than 8 bit (256 colors) was the solution for me, too.

Answer (score 2):

Using Remmina to connect to macOS screensharing + vnc, I had to disable encryption to make it work.

[image]

Comment: I agree with you.  I could not connect until I disabled encryption. Then `remmina` gave me VNC password and it worked.

Comment: Performance of macOS included VNC server is very bad. A rebooted version of VineVNC is way faster. https://github.com/stweil/OSXvnc

You should disable mac's default VNC server and add OSXvnc in the firewall, privacy and accessibility settings.