# Remmina "unable to establish connection to RDP server:" to macbook

Tags: mac, remote, remmina

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. My Remmina has worked fine, connecting to windows and other Linux machines. But it has now refused to connect to my mac book.
The server is fine. `Ping, nmap, ssh` all work.
I have chosen RDP protocol and LTS for security and has enabled "screen sharing" on macbook. 
But Remmina still won't connect.

What should I do.

Comment: I believe it is VNC and not RDP.  At least that is the only way I could get it to work:  https://askubuntu.com/a/774006/231142

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your helps. But removing the known_hosts file didn't work...

Comment: When I use VNC instead, it keeps sending me authentication errors saying my password to user is incorrect (even though it is correct because ssh worked...)

Comment: The password is limited to like 8 characters or something like that.  It is a different password than ssh.  I am not in front of mine as the moment to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac Screen Sharing uses VNC for the connection.  RDP will not work in this situation.

When you setup Screen Sharing on the Mac you give it a separate password than what you use for ssh which uses your standard login password of the Mac.  The username you use when setting up Remmina is the same username you log into the Mac with if you're the administrator.  You could also set the users with access in the `Allow access for:` box.  The password is the one you setup in the Screen Sharing, within the `Computer Settings...` button, which is limited to 8 characters.

This screenshot came from within Remmina connected to my Macbook showing the VNC password limited to 8 characters when I set it up:

[image]

This is how my Remmina settings connecting to my Macbook look:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just want to note that my Remmina crashed unless I set the color to `High color 16bpp` as shown here.